# Using two of the same jQuery plugin (Kwicks) on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, kwicks

I'm using the jQuery plugin 'Kwicks' on a site and having some conflicts.The plugin is working fine for the navigation, but I want to do the same thing for a separate, smaller nav (still using Kwicks) for social media at the top of the page. I've tried everything a novice such as myself could do but still cannot get the second Kwicks nav to function.

Here is the site: http://www.webexplosive.com/accu1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of posting a link to your site, can you copy the relevant JS code into your question above?  Comment it with indications of what works, what doesn't, and why you think it fails.

Comment: A quick glance at your page source reveals that you are including all the `<script>` tags twice. Each should be called only once. And you have two `$(document).ready()` blocks when you can execute all the ready code in one such statement.

Comment: So should I call all of the <script> lines, as well as the $(document).ready() in the first appearing div?

Comment: Put the `<script>` tags including the one `$(document).ready()` in the `<head>` tag. They don't need to be anywhere near the div that uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all include you're javascript files into the head section of the page and its only needed once.

```
<head>
 <script src='js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 <script src='js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 <script src='js/jquery.kwicks.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
```

Second you're reference to the menus are the same, so the plugin will be confused and will only get one ( depends on how the plugin handles the selector )

So to fix the problem give you're ul tags a id attribute like menu1 and menu2 ( unique )

```
<ul class='kwicks1 kwicks-vertical' id='menu1'>
    ...
</ul>
<ul class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal' id='menu2'>
   ...
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu1').kwicks({
        size: 125,
        maxSize: 250,
        spacing: 2,
        behavior: 'menu',
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            isVertical: true
    });
    $('#menu2').kwicks({
                size: 125,
                maxSize : 250,
                spacing : 2,
                behavior: 'menu' ,
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
            });
});
</script>
```

Comment: And if the parameters for all of them are the same, they can go in a single selector:  `$('#menu1, #menu2').kwicks({....});`

Comment: Success! thank you so much, Christiaan. You've been more than help

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/CXu4n/

```
$('.kwicks-horizontal').kwicks({
    size: 125,
    maxSize : 250,
    spacing : 2,
    behavior: 'menu' ,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce' ,
    isVertical: false
});
$('.kwicks-vertical').kwicks({
    size: 200,
    maxSize : 300,
    spacing : 1,
    behavior: 'menu' ,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce' ,
    isVertical: true
});
```